# SQL SERVER TEMP FILE

Tags: sql-server

Can I delete the SQL Server temp file from the temp folder? I don't have enough space and temp folder contain 13 GB to data.

Comment: No you cannot simply delete files belonging to SQL server - I strongly recommend you let someone with experience in SQL server handle this.

Comment: Consider you have a running process and meanwhile delete files from temp folder related to that running process.What would be the result !..Consider posting the question in dba community in stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do that on PROD**
On a development SQL Server server on your own computer, if no one is using it and nothing is running on it and if loosing data does not really matter, you can do this:

- Restart SQL Server service
- Run both or either of these query

  ```
  USE [tempdb]
  GO
  DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'temp file name' , 1000)
  GO
  USE [tempdb]
  GO
  DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'temp log file name' , 1000)
  GO
  ```

Replace 1000 by the size you want in MB when SQL Server starts.
Replace the name of the data and log file by their names. You can get their names with this query:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO
Select name, * From sys.database_files
```

**SQL Server needs this database (tempdb) and it will grow again sooner or later. This is normal.**

Answer (score 0):

-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName]
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
```

-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (databaseName_log, 1);
GO
```

-- Reset the database recovery model.

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```